# Blank external monitor, although external is detected ok, - only solution is reboot - any suggestions?

Tags: xubuntu, multiple-monitors, display, reboot

I have xubuntu install on 2009 toshiba portege r600 10q

When I connect external display to the VGA port the new screen is detected, but no signal is sent to it - the screen stays blank and goes to power save mode. I have tried all options in display menu but nothing works....

....If I reboot the computer, however, the second screen starts working immediately.

So my question is the following.

Is there a background process I can restart of something else I can do to get the second screen working without a reboot?

Many thanks in advance ( and yes I have tried to look through questions and answers here and elsewhere to find solution to this problem )

---

**Edit** with output of

```
xrandr --query
```

Note that identical output is obtained after reboot (with screen working) and after connecting screen without rebook (with screen not working...)

---

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3200 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected primary 1280x800+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1280x800      60.15*+
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   640x480       59.94  
   640x400       60.00  
DVI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA1 connected 1920x1080+1280+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.08    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00  
   720x400       70.08  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: have you tried `xrandr` command?

Comment: rebooted without screen connected - then reconnected and the monitor is successfully detected. xrandr gives sensible output for connected monitor....

Comment: ... but still the same problem - monitor connected but no signal going to it and monitor is in sleep mode

Comment: tried 'xrandr --output VGA1 --off' -- and then 'xrangdr --output VGA --auto' but no joy. The screen on the laptop expects tha the extra monitor is there after turning it on and the mouse can be lost on the other screen when the screens are extended side by side.

Comment: connect your monitor to your laptop, run `xrandr --query`, add the output to your question.

Comment: @Ravexina - edited with output of `xrandr - -query`

Comment: whats happens when you run `xrandr --query` while your monitor does not work (Without reboot to get it work).

Comment: @Ravexina - exactly the same output when the monitor is not working - exactly - I checked with `diff`

Comment: Okay, try this command when your monitor does not works: `xrandr --output VGA1 --output 1280x800 --same-as LVDS1`

Comment: @Ravexina - I get `warning: output 1280x800 not found; ignoring`

Comment: Use `1024x768` instead.

Comment: @Ravexina i get... `warning: output 1024x768 not found; ignoring` -- thanks for your help with this...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56947/discussion-between-ravexina-and-tom).